# Where does a soul go after complete liberation?

Tags: atma

If the only purpose of death and rebirth is to break away from it, why does it exist in the first place? When a soul is liberated and free from rebirth, can it still return if it wants to?

Comment: Earth is not the only place, there are other dimensions as well. Earth is a place for physical presence and for that we need a body and for a body we need to take birth and if we take birth we have to die as well, hence the cycle.

Comment: You're just stating the obvious. But why would we want to be born only to have the goal never to be born again

Comment: The other obvious fact is that you get into the cycle of birth & death to clear off your karmic debts! The sooner you get rid of that, the earlier you move on to the next dimension!

Comment: But my question is not about just any next dimension. Next dimension still means some sort of a birth. If a soul gets liberated from birth, it doesn't just go to the next dimension(heaven, or whatnot) it just comes back to origin, source, God. But why would it just want to get back to square one. To me this doesn't look like progress.